# Remove error message in TextFormField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, textformfield

Hi I want to remove error message caused by validator in TextFormField widget after I submit a form  in flutter.
Ps : I want the error message disappeared after I select again the TextFormField to write into it again.

```
            TextFormField(
                controller: _emailController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null ||
                      value.isEmpty ||
                      !EmailValidator.validate(value)) {
                    return nullEmailMsg;
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: emailHint,
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your `TextFormField` inside a `Form` with the property `autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction`, the validation function should trigger when you select again or change the text.

If the validation function is satisfied, the error message will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the autoValidateMode method in TextFormField.

Here, is the some of the reference:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutovalidateMode-class.html